# Saving and Restoring Objects In Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, object, raphael

I am creating a basic web-based diagramming tool using Javascript and the Raphael Library to create the shapes. I would now like to know how to save and restore objects that i have created.

Belows code creates a basic shape, and enables dragging. How would i go about being able to save and restore the objects such as this:

```
var cubeD = paper.rect(400, 400, 50, 50);
    cubeD.attr({"fill":"yellow"});
    cubeD.draggable.enable();
    cubeD.name = 'cubeD';
objArray.push(cubeD);
objArray_txt.push(cubeD.name);
objAssoc['cubeD'] = cubeD;
```

I tried JSON to store the object but the following code doesnt seem to work:

```
var myJSON = JSON.encode(cubeD);
```

But i get the error

> TypeError: cyclic object value

What would more experienced developers suggest?

Comment: Are you wanting to save, restore and then *reedit* them using Raphael?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

The [cycle.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/cycle.js) file allows cyclic references.

Then you just need to use those functions to avoid your error and just use the so-called "normal" JSON methods to save and restore your object (ask if you can't figure how). When using the "normal" JSON method to restore the object, don't forget to give a new instance of the constructor of your object as argument so that it has all the methods you need and behave as you expect (because JSON only saves data, not functions and therefore, it can't store the Constructor).

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you said concerning the constructor. I have the problem you're talking about but I'm hoping I won't need to traverse my whole tree structure and try to restore it back its original state (before serialization). There has to be a simpler way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope, you can't store the constructors and if you use the JSON utils, they'll give you back instances of Object... So you have two solutions: use some ninja trick and still use the JSON tools or make your won tool.

Comment: `Node.prototype.toJSON=function(){return JSON.encode([JSON.encode(this.value),JSON.encode(this.children)]);}`. `Node.fromJSON=function(j){var a = JSON.decode(j); return new Node (JSON.decode(a[0]),JSON.decode(a[1])}`. It'd work but it'd add a lot of useless `"`.

Comment: Or you can build you own encoding/decoding tool. Or you encode your object normally with JSON and recursively change it back to use the good constructor.

Comment: Hmmm... this is what I'm trying to avoid. I guess the best approach is to keep my model objects dummy, i.e: simple data transfer objects, then create manager classes that manipulate those objects. This way I would avoid the issue altogether.

Comment: Yup. You could also keep the nodes instances of Object and then have a Tree constructor. The only thing you'd loose is the ability to override methods. Like if you have a method that behave differently on Node and Leaf, you'll have to make it detect the kind of node it's on another way.

Comment: Yes exactly. The reason why I had the methods inside my model objects is because I needed to have some polymorphism going on. I guess I'll have to live without that... Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't bank on being able to serialize an object made by an external framework. Either that API supports it or it doesn't (I'm not familiar with Raphael).

The way to solve this is to have an intermediate format which is probably a plain chunk of JSON, and serialize that. This contains the spec to your object. A method would call your API to build the object from your JSON object. This would be called after deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

I use this library on most of my projects:
https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

It has a `$.toJSON` method that will serialize/deserialize javascript into a string.  I'm not sure if this is the best approach but it certainly works for us.  I put the JSON in a cookie and read from it as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try this [Raphael SketchPad](http://ianli.com/sketchpad/)